# Is it possible to install n98-magerun modules that are project specific with a project's composer.json?

Tags: php

Is it possible to install n98-magerun modules that are project specific with a project's composer.json?

It seems with the reading I have done that modules can be placed in the users home directory, or system wide in the /usr/local/share directory:

- /usr/local/share/n98-magerun/modules
- ~/.n98-magerun/modules
- MAGENTO_ROOT/lib/n98-magerun/modules

I have certain projects that use a specific n98-magerun module with additional commands that I want to make required, so I want to use composer to handle the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

For magento 1, you can include an n98-magerun module with a project's composer.json, but n98-magerun will not look for the module using composer's autoloader.  It will still be required to place the module into the MAGENTO_ROOT/lib/n98-magerun/modules directory.

Example project's composer.json:

```
"require": {
  "additional-magerun/module": "dev-master"
}
```

Example magerun module's composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "additional-magerun/module",
    "type": "magento-module",
    "description": "Example description",
    "license": "OSL-3.0",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer": "*"
    }
}
```

The example magerun module's composer.json used the magento-hackathon composer module to copy the module from vendor directory to magento/lib directory.

See example modman file:

```
src/lib/n98-magerun/modules/additionalMagerun lib/n98-magerun/modules/additionalMagerun
```